# Search bar bound on command with predicate don't work. Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

**After such a binding, it is impossible to focus on the search bar.** When tapped  nothing happens. After calling `ChangeCanExecute()` SearchBar's property `IsEnabled` changes to `true` and that's all.

Can't figure out where the error is.

Xamarin.Forms version: 4.8.0.1451

.NET Standard 2.1

My view:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SearchBarTest"
             x:Class="SearchBarTest.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:TestViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <StackLayout>
        <SearchBar SearchCommand="{Binding TestCommand}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

View model:

```
internal class TestViewModel
{
    private bool isInitialized;

    public Command TestCommand { get; }

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            isInitialized = true;

            Debug.WriteLine($">>> Initialized: {isInitialized}");

            TestCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
        });

        TestCommand = new Command(() =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(">>> Command invoked.");
        }, () => isInitialized);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you look in your Debug output if you have any Binding errors?

Comment: @o_w, yes, there are no error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to click the **Search** Icon from **Input Keyboard**, then the `SearchCommand` will be invoked.

[image]

Then the output:

```
12-31 11:20:29.425 I/AssistStructure(31728): Flattened final assist data: 2560 bytes, containing 1 windows, 9 views
[0:] >>> Command invoked.
```

==========================update===============================

I have checked the sample, the problem has been found. You add `Thread.Sleep(5000)` in the Task thread. It will make the `isInitialized = true` later than invoke `TestCommand` code.

**Therefore**, `TestCommand` can not be executed all the time.

The **solution** that you need to comment this line code `Thread.Sleep(5000)`.

```
...
public TestViewModel()
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //Thread.Sleep(5000);

        isInitialized = true;

        Debug.WriteLine($">>> Initialized: {isInitialized}");

        TestCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
    });

    TestCommand = new Command(() =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(">>> Command invoked.");
    }, () => isInitialized);
}
...
```

Comment: @Jiang The problem isn't that I can't call the command. The problem is that when I click on the search bar, nothing happens. The keyboard doesn't appear and the searh bar is not focused. This happens exactly when the search bar is binded to a command with a predicate.

Comment: @tragacheyskiy What is the version of Xamarin Forms used in your project? The shared code works in my local site.

Comment: @Jiang My current version: 4.8.0.1451. I tried latest version (4.8.0.1821) and tried change .NET Standard version but there are same result.

Comment: @Jiang Also i tried run app on different devices but there are same result too.

Comment: @tragacheyskiy Do you have a test in a physical device? If you have time, you could share the sample project link here. I will check that in my local site.

Comment: @Jiang Yes, as i said earlier i tried run an app on different physical devices and on emulator. Here is project repository: [link](https://github.com/tragacheyskiy/SearchBarTest)

Comment: @tragacheyskiy Thanks for sharing. I have found the reason. Because you set `Thread.Sleep(5000);`, it will result `isInitialized = true;` later than binding `TestCommand` for 'SearchBar`. Then `canExecute` of `TestCommand` always be false. Then the tap event will not work.